# Variants in the Mushaf of Uthman?

Tags: quran, quran-recitation, uloom-al-quran, qiraat, mushaf

How can Qiraat arise if the majority of the Quran was written in the Quraishi Dialect? I previously asked the same question but no reasonable answer. I might have misunderstood the meaning of the Hadeeth:

**"If you disagree with Zaid bin Thabit at any point, write in the dialect of Quryaish. Verily, the Quran was revealed in their tongue."**

Please, explain it to me, I really dont understand?
Also, do we know that Uthman purposely allowed these differences?

Comment: 1. "If you disagree" means it's only when they disliked or disagreed with Zaid. 2. Even the Quraishis recited with different recitations... There was no such thing as one recitation of Quraish. 3. Even when the mushaf was written according to one dialect, that still allows other people to recite their own recitations as long as it matches the mushaf because the mushaf did not have dots.

Comment: As for whether Uthman (RA) purposely allowed differences, that is certainly implied in his actions when he did not put dots in the mushaf although it was possible. Also, even if he didn't intend for it, doesn't really make a difference to us. As long as the qiraat come from Allah (and they are all authentic and mutawatir), it doesn't make a difference whether Uthman (RA) intended for them to exist.

Comment: It is also evident in the Sahabah's actions when they had no trouble reciting their own recitations when it matched the mushaf (which is how the different recitations spread), and Uthman (RA) never stopped them.

Comment: Interesting. Could it also mean that if the consonantal structure matched the Quraishi dialect then it could be included and if it didn't then the Quraishi dialect it is.

Comment: Regarding your view if the Quraishis had different recitations... The 7 Ahruf were revealed after the migration and it would be impossible if the Quraishis had different recitations before hijrat

Comment: They would have different recitations after hijrah. Obviously, a lot of the Quran was not revealed until after hijrah and most Sahabah even the Quraishis didn't learn the Quran except after hijrah.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is related to the majority of the Qur'an this is the explanation made by many scholars. If we assume that the Qur'an was revealed in at least seven Arabic languages this would mean that at least 15% was revealed in the language of Quraysh.

However the prophet () transmitted it or it was revealed to him in 7 ahruf.
Further this is not a Hadith but a statement of a Sahabi (). Which might end up as an opinion.

Comment: How can it be? After the migration, the Prophet PBUH still had his Quraishi friends. They could not understand if it was in another dialect.

Comment: @KhizerKhan if you followed my recommendation to check posts on the [tag:qiraat] you'd know better. The prophet () was able to recite and speak languages (or dialects) which he had never learned before. In fact the major issue with at least fasih Arabic languages is the difference of meanings of a word in other cases it is rather the pivoting or misplacement  or skipping of letters.

Comment: I know Prophet (PBUH) knew other dialects. I'm not saying that. My question is: How could qiraat (which includes mixture of dialects) arise if the Quran was written in (mainly) ONE dialect? Did Uthman (R.A) say you can recite it in other ways?

Comment: @KhizerKhan the qur'an was and is not written in one dialect, how often do I need to repeat this?

Comment: The qur'an was first written and compiled at the time of abu Bakr by Zaid who is not from Quraish it was secondly complied by Zaid + a committee at the time of 'Uthman this time including somebody from Quraish. The qur'an we recite today and which is printed in Moshafs includes many words that were unknown or not used by Quraysh, what other proof do you need?

Comment: I think you are too lazy! Sorry this is my last reply! I'm really tired of repeating things that are on the site this is not how this site works! Check the site first before asking what is answered!

Comment: What?! I have been searching the WHOLE internet for the last 2 weeks and I cannot find anything related. I dont like to ask questions. I only do it when I dont find anything. And FYI I have looked through all the questions on this site to related to Qira'at! This is just nonsense to me.

Comment: Also, I was trying to edit the comment and it got duplicated so it might be a misunderstanding that I asked for the proof twice. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

in reality there are several dialects of Quraiche Arabic that's why several verses of the holy quran have different quiraates